# Who is the original artist of the comic on the blog post "Do large language models know what they are talking about?"

Tags: discussion, images, blog, copyright, attribution

The blog post [Do large language models know what they are talking about?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/03/do-large-language-models-know-what-they-are-talking-about/) has the comic:

> [image]
>
> A: It is time to learn about magic circles.
> B: ugh, why is it so complex? ... What does this symbol in the center do?
> A: It's Levr's symbol, a crucial patter to pull arcane power into reality.
> B: What does this diamond do?
> A: It's Kier's symbol, which isn't actually necessary anymore... but the whole spell falls apart without it for some reason.
> B: Then what does this---
> A: I don't know, I just copied it from Arcane Overflow and it works.

I found it via Google Image Search on [iFunny](https://br.ifunny.co/picture/tris-time-to-learn-about-magic-circles-ugh-why-it-cMwqnusEA), dated 3 Feb (presumably 2023).  Without additional attribution, I would assume it was drawn by the author of the blog post, but maybe leaving off credit is an oversight.

**Question**: Who is the original artist of the comic on the blog post "Do large language models know what they are talking about?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was posted in the r/comics subreddit by u/PLutonium273 on February 2, 2023 under the title [[OC] Magic coding](https://www.reddit.com/r/comics/comments/10rukp8/oc_magic_coding/). Taking the "OC" at face value, u/PLutonium273 would presumably be the original artist.

Comment: Question is, did SE just take the comic without permission or attribution?

Comment: That reddit account hasn't posted any other comics of the same style, which is odd considering how polished it is. The image is cropped on the right side, which may indicate some identifying mark was removed. This is exactly why every artist should put their signature at least partly over the content. My husband signs everything he puts up, even if he has no intention of giving people a hard time for passing it around. A unique signature would allow us to maybe track down and enjoy the artist's other comics. Not being able to figure out who created it doesn't mean it's OK to use it though.

Comment: Same author also claims credit for it in the comments of a different reddit thread where it was posted (https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/10rv8sy/dont_question_it/)

Comment: @ColleenV Presumably goldPseudo refers to the comment by u/PLutonium273, not the post: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/10rv8sy/comment/j70shjn/

Comment: Thanks. Apparently that's the only comic of that style they've ever created? And they clipped the edge of it off when they posted it? Weird.

Comment: We've now added a caption to the image in the blog post linking back to that Reddit post as the source.

Comment: They also apparently made the comic [Asian Rick and Morty](https://www.reddit.com/r/comics/comments/un8sr3/asian_rick_and_morty_oc/) (with a similar but less polished art style), but it's pretty buried under their other activity.

Comment: @Laurel I guess their signature is that they consistently chop off the right side of their work? :) Maybe it's something to do with upload constraints on reddit.